# Optimize time range query in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Assume I have a table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `start_time` timestamp,
  `end_time` timestamp,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX idx_start_time_end_time (`start_time`, `end_time`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then, I want to retrieve data that occur in the time range `2023-01-01T00:00:00Z` - `2023-01-15T23:59:59Z`. I use this query:

```sql
SELECT id, schedule_name, start_time, end_time
WHERE start_time < '2023-01-15 23:59:59' AND end_time > '2023-01-01 00:00:00';
```

I try to use `EXPLAIN` and find that the index `idx_start_time_end_time` is hit. But I was not sure, is the query really optimal?

Another case, how about if I have another similar table but the type of column `start_time` and `end_time` is `int` which hold unix timestamp with default value is 0. Is the similar query optimal enough?

```sql
SELECT id, event, start_time, end_time 
WHERE start_time < 1673801999 AND end_time > 1672506000;
```

Comment: There is not much scope for further optimisation, there are only 2 predicates. One observation don't use 23:59:59 MySQL permits fractional seconds for TIME , DATETIME , and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. so you would be better off using < '2023-01-16 00:00:00' and never fall into a sub-second trap.

Comment: *But I was not sure, is the query really optimal?* Create generated column which converts your datetime values to numbers and considers the range as a segment on the timeline. This allows you to create spatial index by this column and search your data very fast using according spatial function(s). The column may be virtual and hidden, if the server version allows. PS. I think that your current index effectively serves your current query. But if your actual queries are more complex then the above technique may be effective.